# Python script fails with coordinate variables (lat, lon) due to argument 2 of type 'double'

Tags: python, csv, coordinates, typeerror, ogr

I am plotting points using ogr in Python (Python 3!), and it works fine if I input my coordinates into the code as numbers, but the following code fails if I try and use the coordinates from a csv file.

Working code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(40.729047, -73.957472)
print(point.ExportToWkt())
```

Code that breaks:

```
from osgeo import ogr

datatest = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

p1_lat, p1_lon = datatest['POINT1_LAT'], datatest['POINT1_LON']

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(p1_lat, p1_lon)
print(point.ExportToWkt())
```

That second example fails with the error `TypeError: in method 'Geometry_AddPoint', argument 2 of type 'double'`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it so that the code can call coordinates from my csv file? Thanks.

EDIT: as requested, if I print the two variables I get:

```
0    40.729047
Name: POINT1_LAT, dtype: float64
0   -73.957472
Name: POINT1_LON, dtype: float64
```

EDIT2: This is Python 3

Comment: Can you print p1_lat and p1_lon?

Comment: it might be the encoding: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53920/ogr-createlayer-returns-typeerror. Try `pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @Sri - I added the print output... it says float64. Peter - that didn't seem to work?

Comment: You'd  better ask this kind of question there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding pandas dataframes with AddPoint instead of floats.

```
import pandas as pd

pts = pd.DataFrame({'p': [3.4532], 'q' : [5.674]})

print(pts['p'])
print(pts['q'])

print(float(pts['p'][0]))
print(float(pts['q'][0]))
```

```
0    3.4532
Name: p, dtype: float64
0    5.674
Name: q, dtype: float64
3.4532
5.674
```

This should work: -

```
from osgeo import ogr

datatest = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

p1_lat, p1_lon = datatest['POINT1_LAT'], datatest['POINT1_LON']
p1_lat = float(p1_lat[0])
p1_lon = float(p1_lon[0])

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(p1_lat, p1_lon)
print(point.ExportToWkt())
```